# How can this problem be solved with partial fractions? (Zero order holder with g(s) block function)

Tags: control, control-system, dsp, homework, z-transform

im trying to figure out how to solve this problems for values a=2; actually im stuck, professor told me how to work it, but i cant figure out what to do exactly, we are using partial fractions inverse z transform to solve and this is the problem:

[image]

it is asking for the transient response in unit step

I upload a example he sent to us with a=1, but i dont know how to work it properly to be true.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I tried to follow the things on the whiteboard but I couldn't get what is going on, but this is how you would get partial fractions once you find your system \$H(z)\$)

When you have a system with many poles such as 
$$ H(s) = \frac{s+d}{(s+a)(s+b)} $$
or a discrete one such as
$$ H(z) = \frac{z+d}{(z+a)(z+b)} $$
You can apply the [Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) method to get the partial fraction expansion.
With it, you want to change
$$ H(z) = \frac{z+d}{(z+a)(z+b)} = \frac{d_1}{z+a}+\frac{d_2}{z+b}.$$

To do so, you multiply them by zeros which will cancel one of the poles, and evaluate them at \$z\$ value of the cancelled pole, to obtain those coefficients \$d_1, d_2\$. 
$$ \left[(z+a)H(z)\right]\big\rvert_{z=-a} = d_1,$$
$$ \left[(z+b)H(z)\right]\big\rvert_{z=-b} = d_2,$$
That way, you can find a partial fraction expansion of \$H(z)\$
$$ H(z) = \frac{d_1}{z+a}+\frac{d_2}{z+b}.$$

And since those terms are readily available in a Z transform table, you can convert them to obtain the time-domain of \$H(z)\$
$$ h(n) = \mathcal{Z}^{-1}(\frac{d_1}{z+a})+\mathcal{Z}^{-1}(\frac{d_2}{z+b}).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, well, i think i got the partial fraction and evaluation part, but i cant figure out yet what to do with the chance of a=2, as i understand i have to multiply (1/2) in both side of this operation (a)/(s(s+a)=(1-e^at)/(z-1)(z-e^at), but i dont know what to do next with the problem, as i understand  have to work with g(z), but dont know how, any advice?